# NetBeans open project problem

Tags: java, netbeans, project

I created a NetBeans project. I took the project folders zipped to another machine and tried opening it in NetBeans. NetBeans didn't identify it as a NetBeans project. I have transfered projects in this way before but why is it not working now? Are any of my project files corrupted. Is there any way to retrieve my files from this?

Comment: You should check the following:

1. the IDE log (look for a way to open it in the View menu.

2. make sure that the IDE you are using has the same features installed and enabled. Look at the dialog that open when you use the Plugins item from the Tools menu... on both systems (the source and destination).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using create new project from existing resources. This may solve the issue.

Comment: Is this a netbeans bug? I tried you solution and get `is already a netbeans project` and I cant proceed.

Comment: You may need to delete `nbproject` folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

1. Create a new project on the target machine
2. Find where the project you want to open is stored and open the src folder.
3. Copy all the files and stuff in the /src folder
4. Go on Netbeans, expand the tree view of the project you have just created, right click on source packages and click paste. It should paste the files in the /src folder as packages. You should also see the code these packages contain.

Answer (score 2):

I just copied whole project into place in system where NetBeans stores projects (in windows it's user\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ by default), then started NetBeans and voila - worked great :)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this solution and it worked for me:  http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Netbeans-Crashes-Since-Windows-Update-td5752603.html

The fix is to remove the GodMode shortcut that may have been created on your Desktop or on the root of the %systemdrive%.