# How does build.xml work in NetBeans?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

I'm trying to switching from *Eclipse* to *NetBeans* for java ee, im noticing that when i delete a project from the project window ( i don't delete definitely ), the file *build.xml* disappears from the folder and i'm not able to reopen or import it anymore, i'm sorry if this sounds naive but i've tried to google it and i can't find anything, why would this happen ?

Comment: I think the following solution should work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2834019/4683085

Comment: yes i tried that one before, i probably did something wrong, it worked now

Answer (score 0):

The *build.xml* file is an *Ant* script, that *NetBeans* uses to build the project. It's like the *.project* file for *Eclipse*.

When you delete a project from *NetBeans*, the *NetBeans* configuration for that project is deleted too.

In order to explain "How does build.xml work in NetBeans", maybe this documentation can help you:
https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-ant.html

Comment: I've seen that tutorial, that doesn't tell me what i should do with projects once i close them

Comment: That is not what you asked in fist place. Your question is "how does build.xml work in NetBeans"